# JSF 2.0,JPA2.0 eclipseLink 2.5.1 7 EJB 3.0 application Migrating from websphere 8.0 to liberty 8.5.5.9 profile

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, logback, slf4j

`JSF 2.0,JPA2.0 eclipseLink 2.5.1 7 EJB 3.0` application Migrating from websphere to liberty profile
getting below error while migrating from websphere to websphere liberty profile

> [ERROR   ] CWWKZ0002E: An exception occurred while starting the
>   application fagerEar. The exception message was:
>   com.ibm.ws.container.service.state.StateChangeException:
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.Logger

Comment: I do not understand telegraphic style question: use punctuation, use list, format your "error stacktrace" (if I call that a stack), reduce your problem scope (clearly Logback / SLF4J centered, JPA is most likely innocent here). Provide some relevant information (configuration files or such)

Answer (score 0):

Your slf4j jar which contains org.slf4j.Logger class is missing in the MANIFEST.MF file of the project which is trying to load it. If this error is occurring in your Web project, please add the slf4j jar in the MANIFEST.MF of your web project.